# Pandas unable to read SQL headers - Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

I'm using the pyodbc driver and attempting to read an sql server database. The resulting dataframe has empty column headers like shown below

[image: screenshot of the ipython console]

I've cast some fields to date / datetime type and those changes seem to be visible without the respective headers

Comment: You're likely doing just `CAST(foo AS thing)` instead of `CAST(foo AS thing) AS column_name`

Comment: wow, such a stupid thing. thanks it worked. if you can add this as an answer, i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a bare column name is included in a SELECT statement its name is automatically used in the result set:

```
1> SELECT create_date FROM sys.tables WHERE name='team';
2> go
create_date
-----------------------
2021-01-02 11:06:23.763

(1 rows affected)
```

However, if the column is the result of an expression then most database engines do not return a column name …

```
1> SELECT create_date, CAST(create_date AS date) FROM sys.tables WHERE name='team';
2> go
create_date
----------------------- ----------------
2021-01-02 11:06:23.763       2021-01-02

(1 rows affected)
```

… unless we explicitly provide it using AS:

```
1> SELECT create_date, CAST(create_date AS date) AS date_only FROM sys.tables WHERE name='team';
2> go
create_date             date_only
----------------------- ----------------
2021-01-02 11:06:23.763       2021-01-02

(1 rows affected)
```